# Check out source code from Source Control Explorer and not from Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

We are using VS2010 and we have migrated project **X** from VSS to TFS2010.

We have two administrator users lets say **admin1** (project colection admin) and **admin2** (**X** project admin). Both admin1 and admin2 are domain users.

The problem is, **admin1** can checkout any items on project **X** while **admin2** receives the error below:

"The item '...' could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it."

**admin2** receives this error only when he tries to checkout from Solution Explorer.  There is no problem when he attempts checking out from source control explorer.

The source control bindings of the solution is correct(I've already checked 'File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control')

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Comment: 1. Double check the workspace mappings of server to local folders. 2. Using the command line, when in a local folder mapped in the workspace, what does `tf get` return?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a file under your solution which VS believes is under source control but does not exists in source control.

I recommend you create a new workspace and do it.